# integration bounds for triple integral

Tags: calculus

Im still working on finding the right bounds for my triple integrals, with good help from this forum I have come a bit further, I think.

$ \int_D \text{ at the domaine } \{(x,y,z) | 0 \leq z \leq 1 - x^2 - \frac{y^2}{4} \} $

So I have plugged in the shape in Geogebra: $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}$ and then two planes: $z=0 \text{ and } z = 1$.  So I clearly see the shape I have to integrate and from which points. But Im not quite shure how to write the bounds, feel like I'm guessing. My initial line of thinking is that x,y,z all share a beginning point at (0,0,0) and then they move in their respective directions until z = 1:

$ \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{x^2} \int_{0}^{y^2/4} dzdxdy $

Is that the correct way to conceptualize is?

Would be very happy for feedback and help!

Comment: You asked this question earlier. Instead of asking the same question again, you can edit your question with the progress you made and seek further help.

Comment: Your integral is not set up correctly. You meant $dz$ last? If the order is $dx \, dy \, dz$, upper bound of $x$ will be in terms of $y, z$, of $y$ will be in terms of $z$, of $z$, it will be $1$. Use $x = \cos \theta, y = 2 \sin \theta$ to make the integral workable.

Comment: @Ok, I have edited my first question about the integral. Didn't mean to ask the same question, but wanted help with the next step. Yes, I meant to write dz at the end. I'm still a bit confused about order of integrals.

Comment: My suggestion in that case is to work with volume of a simple circular paraboloid first $z = x^2 + y^2$ cut by plane $z = 1$. Are you able to get the limits right for that?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is more advanced than what you're used to, but this is how I would go about it:

Normally, if the upper bound for $z$ was $1 - x^2 - y^2$, we would convert to cylindrical coordinates using the transformations $x = r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta), z=z$. This works very nicely because the $x^2 + y^2$ in the bound turns into $r^2$.

Here, our upper bound is an elliptical paraboloid, with $z = 1 - x^2 - \dfrac{y^2}{4}$, so if we want the same nice transformation, we need $x^2 + \dfrac{y^2}{4} = 1$. We can achieve this with the transformation $x = r\cos(\theta), y = 2r\sin(\theta), z = z$, sort of an elliptical version of our standard cylindrical coordinates.

After this transformation, our bounds of integration change to $0 \leq z \leq 1 - r^2$. Solving $1- r^2 \geq 0$ should give you $0 \leq r \leq 1$, and then our angle makes a full rotation with $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

(Edit: The $r \geq 0$ comes as a matter of convention, you could alternatively use $-1 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ but it confuses things a little.)

The only thing left to do is to calculate the determinant of the Jacobian. If you're not familiar with the Jacobian, it's basically where the $r dr d\theta$ comes from when you integrate with polar coordinates: it accounts for the transformation of the area or volume element itself.

The Jacobian of our transformation is: 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & 2\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
-r\sin(\theta) & 2r\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

and its determinant is $\cos(\theta)\cdot2r\cos(\theta) - 2\sin(\theta)\cdot-r\sin(\theta)+0 = 2r(\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)) = 2r$.

This result should make sense intuitively if you think about it as first making the transformation $y = 2y$ and then converting to cylindrical.

Now we should be able to put everything together to get our integral:
$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-r^2}2rdzdrd\theta$.

Hope this helps!